# Why do I get a "Could not find file" error in Powershell ISE but not the console?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that, at one point in the script, starts a process and passes a list of arguments to the process argument, like so:

```
$parmArgList = "/D build_path=C:\My_Folder\Test\script orca_bootstrap.data"
$ProcessInfo.Arguments = $parmArgList
...
...
...
$Process.Start()
while (($str=$Process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) -new $null){
     Write-Host $str
}
```

If I right click on this script inside the directory it is located within, click on "Run with Powershell", the script goes off without any issues. But if I run it inside the ISE, I get a "Could not open input file 'orca_bootstrap.dat'" error.

My first thought was to change the directory of Powershell ISE to that of my script using the "cd" command (since it starts by default in C:\Users\My_UserName). I did this, and I'm still getting the error. I even took it a step further and did a Get-Location on both the Powershell ISE and the console to confirm the script itself was running in the same directory.

Why is this script able to run in the console, but not the Powershell ISE? What else can I do to troubleshoot or fix this?

Comment: I suggest you run in debug with breakpoints (I personally use VisualStudio Code), this should allow you to investigate the exception details with the hope of finding something more useful. I'd also check if the file is actually in use by some other process that is locking it (even if this doesn't seems to be the case)

Comment: Yes, I've tried that but I haven't been able to get much useful information unfortunately. I will say, I did notice when comparing the ProcessInfo between the two, there was a difference in environmental variables. Specifically, the console listed PATHEXT and ISE listed PATH. Any ideas on how this can be related to my issue? A quick google search shows it's just the order the program is looked for, but...I'm not sure how that would be causing the issue..

Comment: Maybe pass the full path to the data file? The process you start, is it in the same folder? looks like the process does not find the file, not the script.